.NET 6.0 error. Could not load file or assembly System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter
I got this error when I set up a .NET Core 6 app:

Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I actually added the package reference. It just does not work.
<PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter" VersionOverride="8.0.0" />


Is this running on Windows or other platforms? If you’re targeting .NET Core or .NET 5+, make sure your project is set up to run on Windows only System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter API is Windows-specific.

It's running on Windows.

you have to dotnet restore or add it through command or nuget package manager the error is because of reffernce but dll of packge is not present

According to your description, I suggest you could firstly make sure you have installed the System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter 8.0.0 from the nuget package.
You could also use this command :
dotnet add package System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter --version 8.0.0

But I suggest you could re-check your project to make sure your project's support version 8 System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.
Its dependencies as below:
It need upgrade some package >=8.0.0

If your project doesn't support this, I suggest you could install the 6.0.1 instead of the 8.0.0.


Use the Version attribute instead of VersionOverride. <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter" Version="8.0.0" />
Ensure the package is restored and installed correctly. dotnet restore
Ensure you’re targeting a compatible version of .NET and running on Windows.
Clean and rebuild commands are your friend.
Check Assembly Binding Redirects (for .NET Framework)
Check your .csproj file for the target framework: <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>

`
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>

